# How much data do Arch Linux needs to load during installation?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, size

So I'm new to Arch and now I'm doing the installation process I got a internet speed around `10KiB/s` (not sure why) and it's been loading packages for ~2hrs (It starts loading after I run `pacstrap /mnt base base-devel` command).

So due to my horrible internet I want to know what's the total size of the things it requires to load for `pacstrap /mnt base base-devel` command in order to let me have an idea how long will it take to finish the process?

Comment: Did you select a good mirror: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Select_the_mirrors

Comment: Pacstrapping package groups `base` and `base-devel` combined needs to download around 282 MiB. It tells you right before it starts the download, which is easy to miss without the `-i` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` file and move the closest mirror to the top of your file.

[Enabling a specific mirror](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mirrors#Enabling_a_specific_mirror)

> **Tip:**
>
> Uncomment 5 favorite mirrors and place them at the top of the mirrorlist file. That way it's easy to find them and move them around if the first mirror on the list has problems. It also makes merging mirrorlist updates easier.